# Distribution of thermometric devices on earth

Tags: climate, temperature, earth-history, earth-observation

In complex climate models, measurements of Earth-based thermometers are used. What is their geographic distribution - historically? Does each measurement get equal weight?

Comment: Hello, Dee Jay Jay, and welcome to Earth Science SE.  You're asking a good question, but unfortunately your question is too broad and would take an entire textbook to answer.  The short answer is **no**.  The long answer is a mathematical heavy course on [Data assimilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_assimilation).  Also, note that climate models do not really use measurements; they reproduce climate (mean temperature), not weather.  [Re-analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteorological_reanalysis) does use measurements to reproduce the state of the Earth.